# R: How can I use strings of multiple columns as patterns in gsub?

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I need to make a column named `incorrect` that contains all of the words from `written` that do not appear in `target.apple` and `target.banana`.

```
recall <- data.frame(written = c("apples car banana hat pencil r", "papeer apple cars spoon", "dice banaana pen f apple berry"))
recall <- recall %>% mutate(target.apple = str_extract(written,"app([^ ]+)"),
                            target.banana = str_extract(written,"bana([^ ]+)"))
```

Example:

```
                           written  target.apple   target.banana           incorrect
1   apples car banana hat pencil r        apples          banana    car hat pencil r
2          papeer apple cars spoon         apple            <NA>   papeer cars spoon
3   dice banaana pen f apple berry         apple         banaana    dice pen f berry
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` with `rowwise`. First, be sure to `tokenize` the sentences (split into words). Then, `c_across` uses tidy-select statements to create a vector from selected columns, similar to `c(target.apple, target.banana)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tokenizers)

recall %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(incorrect = tokenize_words(written),
           incorrect = toString(incorrect[!incorrect %in% c_across(contains('target'))]))%>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  written                        target.apple target.banana incorrect          
  <chr>                          <chr>        <chr>         <chr>              
1 apples car banana hat pencil r apples       banana        car, hat, pencil, r
2 papeer apple cars spoon        apple        NA            papeer, cars, spoon
3 dice banaana pen f apple berry apple        banaana       dice, pen, f, berry
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NA` values make this a bit tricky, as `str_remove_all()` doesn't handle `NA` patterns (or `pattern = ""`). The neatest way I can think of dealing with this is to create a function `str_remove_any()` that *does* handle `NA` patterns (by ignoring them). Then you can do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

recall <- tibble(
  written = c(
    "apples car banana hat pencil r", 
    "papeer apple cars spoon", 
    "dice banaana pen f apple berry"
  )
)

str_remove_any <- function(x, pattern) {
  not_na <- !is.na(pattern)
  x[not_na] <- str_remove_all(x[not_na], pattern[not_na])
  x
}

recall %>% 
  mutate(
    target.apple = str_extract(written,"app([^ ]+)"),
    target.banana = str_extract(written,"bana([^ ]+)"),
    incorrect = written %>%
      str_remove_any(fixed(target.apple)) %>%
      str_remove_any(fixed(target.banana))
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   written                        target.apple target.banana incorrect           
#>   <chr>                          <chr>        <chr>         <chr>               
#> 1 apples car banana hat pencil r apples       banana        " car  hat pencil r"
#> 2 papeer apple cars spoon        apple        NA            "papeer  cars spoon"
#> 3 dice banaana pen f apple berry apple        banaana       "dice  pen f  berry"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove all instances of `app[^ ]+` and `bana[^ ]+` by substituting them with the empty string:

```
recall$incorrect <- gsub("appl[^ ]+|bana[^ ]+", "", recall$written)
recall$incorrect
[1] " car  hat pencil r" "papeer  cars spoon" "dice  pen f  berry"
```

If your target regexes are many, or procedurally generated, you can `paste` them together to create the matching pattern, using `|` as collapse separator

```
targets <- c("appl[^ ]+", "bana[^ ]+")
recall$incorrect <- gsub(paste(targets, collapse = "|"), "", recall$written)
```